# Defining special function or variable for a derivative in mathematica

Tags: parametric-functions, differentials

I have a question in Mathematica, I would appreciate it if you possibly answered me.
What can I do for defining a special variable for derivative of arbitrary variable. 
For example, imagine I have  a function as following

```
F[a_,b_]:= a  + b
```

Then I want to define

```
D[a,c] == R1
```

Define D[b,c] == R2

and at the end I get:

```
D[F[a,b],c] = R1 + R2
```

can I do something like this in Mathematica?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One possibility: assign `UpValues` to symbols `a` and `b` and use`Dt` instead:

```
Clear[a, b, f, r1, r2]
a /: Dt[a, c] := r1
b /: Dt[b, c] := r2
f[a_, b_] := a + b
```

Then,

```
Dt[f[a, b], c]
(* r1 + r2 *)
```

To see more clearly what's going on with `Dt`, consider:

```
Clear[g]
Dt[g[a, b]]
(* Dt[b] D[g[a, b], b] + Dt[a] D[g[a, b], a] *)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, and one more thing, if the function f[c1_, c2_] and g[c1_,c2_], is there any possiblity to do the same thing for g and f for example  f[c1, c2] /: Dt[f[c1, c2], g[c1,c2]] := r1

Comment: @aminbk: Once you start mixing the definitions like this, it's probably best to go Pillsy's route and use replacement rules.

Answer (score 3):

I like @march's [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100279/531) to use [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html) (as well as the implicit suggestion to use lower-case symbol names), but one alternative approach is to use replacement rules. If they work for your use case, I find them much clearer than setting `UpValues`:

```
Clear[a, b, f, r1, r2];

f[a_, b_] := a + b;

Dt[f[a, b]] 

(* Dt[a, c] + Dt[b, c] *)

% /. {Dt[a, c] -> r1, Dt[b, c] -> r2}

(* r1 + r2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but just one more thing, Now if I have something like this f[a_,b_] and g[a_,b_] how can I define Dt[F[a,b],g[a,b]] ->r1 ?? t